# jQuery JSON and PHP not playing nice

Tags: php, jquery, xml, json

I'm sure this is something simple, but I've been messing with it for days and it is driving me crazy!

I am having trouble getting the proper JSON from an AJAX request.  Interestingly, the same exact issue happens using XML instead of JSON, so I am really confused.  I have simplified things a little bit (not changing the issue) for you guys:

ajax.php:

```
header("Content-type: application/json;");
$data = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);
echo $data;
```

page.php:

```
$.post('ajax.php', { url: 'https://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.103&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=300.02&knowledgeResponseType=application/json' }, function(data){
                                    console.log(data);
                                });
```

Console Output (notice that feed.entry has a length of 0):

```
Object {feed: Object} feed: Object author: Object base: "http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/" category: Array[4] entry: Array[0] id: Object lang: "en" subtitle: Object title: Object updated: Object
```

If you go to that URL, you can clearly see that entry has a length of one.  Here is where it really confuses me:

If I go to ajax.php and copy the output, and then have ajax.php echo the data directly, the console logs the correct info.  Can anyone explain why this is, or how to fix it?

EDIT:

To make it a little bit clearer, here are both JSON trees (the first failing to parse correctly, and the second is correct):

[image: length=0]
[image: length=1]

Answer (score 2):

The 0 does not indicate the number of items in entry; it's the index of the first item in entry, which is described just afterwards

Comment: So 4 is the index of the first entry in the category array?  No, 4 is the length of the array.  Furthermore, when directly echoing the data, the console correctly shows entry[1]. Expanding the tree then shows index 0 has a value of an object.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(data)`

to output JSON in JavaScript, I'm pretty positive you are checking the length of an object as well which will be equal 1 if it exists and 0 if it doesn't. A quick test would be

```
console.log(typeof feed.entry)
```

Comment: I am not trying to output the string of the object, but rather the value of the member of the object contained in the entry array.  Either way, stringify works as expected in both instances (according to the trees that I added after you answered).